# Node js custom callback function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to make a simple authentication with node js. Because I read user data from a database, I have to make it asynchronous. Here's my function, which checks if authentication is ok:

```
function auth(req, callback) {
    var header = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(cb.type);
    console.log("Authorization Header is: ", header);
    if(!header) {
        callback(false);
    }
    else if(header) { 
        var tmp = header.split(' ');
        var buf = new Buffer(tmp[1], 'base64');
        var plain_auth = buf.toString();
        console.log("Decoded Authorization ", plain_auth);
        var creds = plain_auth.split(':');
        var name = creds[0];
        var password = creds[1];

        User.findOne({name:name, password:password}, function(err, user) {
            if (user){
                callback(true);
            }else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });            
    }       
}
```

And here I call the function:

```
auth (req, function (success){                
    if (!success){
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="myRealm');
        res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    }else{                             
        if(user!==req.user) {
            res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
        }else{
            User.findOneAndUpdate({user:userid}, {user:req.body.user, name:req.body.name, email:req.user.email, password:User.generateHash(req.body.password)},
            {upsert:true}, function(err, user) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.status(200).send("OK");
                }else{
                    res.status(400).send("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This gives me error "TypeError: object is not a function", pointing at "callback(false)". I have no idea what could cause this error, as I pass a function as a parameter, and the first log message prints "[function]". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your log message references `cb.type` but your function signature and call show `callback`. I am guessing this inconsistency might be the source of the problem or at least better reveal the issue if they are consistent.

Comment: Actually, all my callbacks are called "cb" in my own code, I just extended them for clarity when I wrote that message.

Comment: I do not see `res` anywhere in the `auth()` method. That will cause problems.  Also, which `callback(false)` is causing problems - the one at the top or bottom of the first code snippet? It looks like it should be working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: object is not a function+nodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005752/typeerror-object-is-not-a-functionnodejs)