# TypeError: object is not a function+nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node js using an online course, following the video but I got this error in the terminal:

```
 TypeError: object is not a function
     at cacheYEntrega (C:\Users\omex\Documents\My Web Sites\cache\server.js:24:14)
     at C:\Users\omex\Documents\My Web Sites\cache\server.js:31:13
     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168:19)
```

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var mymeTypes = {
'.js': 'text/javascript',
'.html': 'text/html',
'.css': 'text/css'
 };

  var cache = {}; //objeto cache que se utilizara para almacenar archivos en    memoria
  function cacheYEntrega(f,cb){
  if(!cache[f]){
    fs.readFile(f, function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            cache[f] = { content: data };
        }
        cb(err, data);

    });
    return;  
    }
     console.log('cargando ' + f + ' de cache');
     cb(null, cache(f).content);
     }

     http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     var buscar = path.basename(decodeURI(request.url)) || 'index.html', f = 'content/' + buscar;
     fs.exists(f, function (exists) {
      if (exists) {
        cacheYEntrega(f, function (err, data) {
            if (err) { response.writeHead(505); reponse.end('Error en el servidor'); return; }
            var headers = { 'Content-type': mymeTypes[path.extname(buscar)]       };
            response.writeHead(200, headers);
            response.end(data);
        });
        return;
    }
 response.writeHead(404);
 response.end('pagina no encontrada');
  });




 }).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `cache(f)` needs to be `cache[f]`, because it's a plain object, not a function.